# Extending default user using Abstract User

Tags: django, django-custom-user

I am trying to add some extra fields in default user model. But the new fields is not showing up in admin page. Here are the models of 'users' app.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    q1 = models.TextField()
    q2 = models.TextField()
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreation(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'q1', 'q2')


class CustomUserChange(UserChangeForm):  
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'q1', 'q2')
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin

from .forms import CustomUserCreation, CustomUserChange
from .models import CustomUser


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreation
    form = CustomUserChange
    list_display = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'q1', 'q2']
    model = CustomUser

admin.site.register(CustomUser, CustomUserAdmin)
```

P.S. I have added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = users.CustomUser` in settings.py

Comment: Can you show your settings file?

Answer (score 1):

In your admin.py file you need to override `UserAdmin` as:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    form = CustomUserChange
    add_form = CustomUserCreation

    list_display = ('email', 'username', 'password', 'q1', 'q2')
    fields = ('email', 'username', 'password', 'q1', 'q2')
    model = CustomUser

admin.site.register(CustomUser, UserAdmin)
```

Check this example in the docs for more understanding [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following things into your django project.

- Have you added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.models.CustomUser'` to your `settings.py` file ?
- Ensure you have added `q1` and `q2` to your `fields` attribute in `CustomUserAdmin` as follow:

  ```
  class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
      add_form = CustomUserCreation
      form = CustomUserChange
      list_display = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'q1', 'q2']
      fields = ['email', 'username', 'password', 'q1', 'q2']
      model = CustomUser
  ```

Comment: I have added AUTH_USER_MODEL. After adding fields attribute. It gives the following error: (admin.E005) both fieldsets and fields are specified

Comment: Also AUTH_USER_MODEL = users.model.CustomUser does not work. users.CustomUser does

Comment: Actually `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is path to your `CustomUser` model
Also could you share your `admin.py`

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a user profile model with a OneToOne relation and fire it up using signal whenever a user has been added without having to touch the User model.

```html
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    q1 = models.TextField()
    q2 = models.TextField()
   
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.q1


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs["instance"]
    if kwargs["created"]:
        user_profile = Profile(user=user)
        user_profile.save()
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```